# iOS 7 simulator update in xcode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

My MAC OS is updated to OS X Mavericks, and xcode to 5.0.2,

After updating xcode iOS simulator 6.0 and 6.1 automatically installed but there is no iOS 7 simulator in installation list. How to get iOS 7 simulator or install.

Anybody help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode 5 comes with iOS 7 sdk and simulator, in other words,  iOS7 simulator is installed by default. However iOS7 is only supported by iPhone Retina and iPad, iPad Retina, therefore you have to select appropriate iOS simulator in your project.

[image: Simulator Selection in Project]
[image: Simulator Selection]

You just need to launch the appropriate iOS simulator (iPhone Retina 3.5-inch for example).
[image: iOS7 Simulator]